# Why are my smart contract rinkeby transactions failing?

Tags: truffle, gas-price, rinkeby

I deployed a smart contract in rinkeby network, and I have no problem deploying the [contract](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x08c1fa540e53c998B5572dA9dd9785f4Ff052704). But when I try to run method addClient() it always fails (Seems to be gas issue).
I tried changing gas price with metamask up to 2-3 ethers but still it failed.

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xd91fdbbf350511591685fcfd37d5d992a50c47f1eb36fc2200aca83d8f08cf2c

Is my method too hungry in gas ? (I don't think so)

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

/**
 * @title Roles
 * @dev Library for managing addresses assigned to a Role.
 */
library Roles {
  struct Role {
    mapping (address => bool) bearer;
  }

  /**
   * @dev give an account access to this role
   */
  function add(Role storage role, address account) internal {
    require(account != address(0));
    require(!has(role, account));

    role.bearer[account] = true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev remove an account's access to this role
   */
  function remove(Role storage role, address account) internal {
    require(account != address(0));
    require(has(role, account));
    role.bearer[account] = false;
  }

  /**
   * @dev check if an account has this role
   * @return bool
   */
  function has(Role storage role, address account)
    internal
    view
    returns (bool)
  {
    require(account != address(0));
    return role.bearer[account];
  }
}
```

there is a call at the constructor level that add contract owner as a client:

```
contract ClientRole {
  using Roles for Roles.Role;

  // Define 2 events, one for Adding, and other for Removing
  event ClientAdded(address indexed account);
  event ClientRemoved(address indexed account);

  // Define a struct 'clients' by inheriting from 'Roles' library, struct Role
  Roles.Role private clients;

  // In the constructor make the address that deploys this contract the 1st Client
  constructor() public {
    _addClient(msg.sender);
  }

  // Define a modifier that checks to see if msg.sender has the appropriate role
  modifier onlyClient() {
    require(isClient(msg.sender));
    _;
  }

  // Define a function 'isClient' to check this role
  function isClient(address account) public view returns (bool) {
    return clients.has(account);
  }

  // Define a function 'addClient' that adds this role
  function addClient(address account) public onlyClient {
    _addClient(account);
  }

  // Define a function 'removeClient' that adds this role
  function removeClient(address account) public onlyClient {
    _removeClient(account);
  }

  // Define a function 'renounceClient' to renounce this role
  function renounceClient() public {
    _removeClient(msg.sender);
  }

  // Define an internal function '_addClient' to add this role, called by 'addClient'
  function _addClient(address account) internal {
    clients.add(account);
    emit ClientAdded(account);
  }

  // Define an internal function '_removeClient' to remove this role, called by 'removeClient'
  function _removeClient(address account) internal {
    clients.remove(account);
    emit ClientRemoved(account);
  }
}
```

Then I use a contract called Verification.sol than inherits Client.sol and I call the method `addClient()` from Verification.sol contract.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import "../coffeeaccesscontrol/PeriRole.sol";
import "../coffeeaccesscontrol/ClientRole.sol";
import "../coffeecore/Ownable.sol";

// Define a contract 'verification'
contract Verification is ClientRole, PeriRole {

  // Define 'owner'
  address owner;

  // Define a variable with number of transaction
  uint  ct;

  // Define a public mapping 'items' that maps the ct to an Item.
  mapping (uint => Item) items;

  // Define a public mapping 'itemsHistory' that maps the ct to an array of TxHash, 
  // that track its journey through the verification -- to be sent from DApp.
  mapping (uint => string[]) itemsHistory;
  
  // Define enum 'State' with the following values:
  enum State 
  { 
    Rendez,  // 0
    PeriProcessed,  // 1
    ClientProcessed,  // 2
    bothPeri  // 3
  }

  State constant defaultState = State.Rendez;

  // Define enum 'VerifClient' with the following values:
  enum VeriClient 
  { 
    noShow,  // 0
    bad,  // 1
    good  // 2
  }

  // Define enum 'VeriPhotoPeri' with the following values:
  enum VeriPhotoPeri 
  { 
    noShow,  // 0
    bad,  // 1
    good  // 2
  }

  // Define enum 'VeriPeri' with the following values:
  enum VeriPeri
  { 
    noShow,  // 0
    bad,  // 1
    good  // 2
  }

  VeriClient constant defaultVeriClient = VeriClient.noShow;
  VeriPhotoPeri constant defaultVeriPhotoPeri = VeriPhotoPeri.noShow;
  VeriPeri constant defaultVeriPeri = VeriPeri.noShow;

  // Define a struct 'Item' with the following fields:
  struct Item {
    uint    ct; // number of verifications in the blockchain
    address ownerID;  // Metamask-Ethereum address of the current owner as the product moves through 8 stages
    address clientID; // Metamask-Ethereum address of the client
    address    periID;  // Metamask-Ethereum address of the peripateticienne
    uint    dateRdv;  // date in digits
    State   itemState;  // Product State as represented in the enum above
    VeriClient itemVeriClient;
    VeriPhotoPeri itemVeriPhotoPeri;
    VeriPeri itemVeriPeri;
  }

(more methods -------------------------------------)
}
```

code version:

```
Truffle v5.4.24 (core: 5.4.24)
Solidity - 0.4.24 (solc-js)
Node v12.0.0
Web3.js v1.5.3
```

truffle-config.js

```
rinkeby: {
  provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/${infuraKey}`),
    network_id: 4,       // rinkeby's id
    gas: 4500000,      // 4500000  // rinkeby has a lower block limit than mainnet
    gasPrice: 10000000000, // 10000000000 
    from: publicAddress // contract owner in rinkeby: 0x08c1fa540e53c998B5572dA9dd9785f4Ff052704
},
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Can you post the contract code (or at least the constructor)? It would help debug obvious issues. My hunch: the `addClient` method has a `onlyClient` modifier, and seeing as in the failed tx you're trying to add yourself as a client, it may be that the contract has no clients yet. If that's the issue, you may have to add youself as the client in the contract constructor e.g. do a _addClient(msg.sender).

Comment: Hi razgraf thanks for your comment I put the 2 contract Client.sol and Verification.sol as an answer below. I already add contract owner in the constructor of client. Just want to say that this method works ok on local chain using ganache when I do the tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contracts are correct, it's just a small details you haven't considered. To recap,

1. You are [deploying](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xe021d642a915f26a42cad5470e6a0c95997ef2667c92a9dbc073371fd1af4452) the contract from the `0x..C9E3` address, thus whitelisting it as a client
2. You are trying to whitelist `0x..C9E3` again by calling addClient

Assuming you are using a version of this [Roles.sol](https://github.com/hiddentao/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/access/Roles.sol) library, if we look at the implementation of `add` we'll notice two checks:

```js
  require(account != address(0)); // is my address valid
  require(!has(role, account)); // is my account new, no client role yet
```

The second transaction you're doing, trying to add `0x..C9E3` will fail due to this second condition not being met.

**Solution:** Try adding another client, with another address. Should work fine!

P.S. When adding more details, please edit your initial post to keep it organized. Also, try looking into more recent openzeppelin access control libraries, always good to keep up with the latest.

Example of bad tx | please call `addClient` with another address as parameter to make this work.

[image]

Comment: Hi @razgraf . Thanks for your reply again.
1) I tried with a different address: _0xDb...C3d9A6_ but I doesn't reject, the transaction just get stuck and never is confirmed: [etherscan rinkeby](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x615834a3a6fc2647ffd953154c8152a7d73b46d9)

I also get a message from metamask that transaction will fail:
**This transaction is expected to fail. Trying to execute it is expected to be expensive but fail, and is not recommended.**

2) Will try to work on updating openzeppelin and Role.sol new version.

Comment: Are you sure you're trying to call from `0x..C9E3` the `addClient(0x..somethingelse)` ? Give another address as argument to the function  ---- The txs you have are still `0x..C9E3` calling addClient on itself. I see: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x27790f95f540b88fad3fa71672e35f7375fd3cd06347e96a1d06df911250b300

Answer (score 0):

You're right indeed, I had an issue with my front-end, which was always using contract owner ethereum addresss in the `{from: }` parameter, instead of the new address to be added.

I managed to confirm the `addClient()` method afterward.
[etherscan transaction](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x546b0e8d86085173d91b8249ff70a86a0688402f2062f622f5fec4eaaea0ebd5)

```
addClient: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var processId = parseInt($(event.target).data('id'));
    
    App.contracts.Verification.deployed().then(function(instance) {
        return instance.addClient(
            App.clientID,
            {from: ownerID}
        );
    }).then(function(result) {
        $("#ftc-item").text(result);
```

Thank you so much for your patience and reply.
Best regards,
Baptiste